# Android application manager shows wrong app name

Tags: package, android

Does anyone know why the application manager, found by going to settings->application manager, is showing the wrong name for my application? I installed my app twice under different names and with different application package names. I can see both named applications under the apps page, but the application manager is showing them as the same name. I need to know which is which so I can force close and uninstall the correct version of my application. Any ideas?

Here's the manifest of the DEMO version of my application, where string/app_name = package_DEMO:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.apps.package_DEMO"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0">

    <uses-sdk 
       android:minSdkVersion="10" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="my.apps.package.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name="my.apps.package.MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:name="my.apps.package.SettingsActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the original's manifest, where string/app_name = package:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.apps.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0">

    <uses-sdk 
       android:minSdkVersion="10" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="my.apps.package.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name="my.apps.package.MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:name="my.apps.package.SettingsActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your manifest.xml

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this problem - i.e. that of the app name showing up incorrectly in Settings->Apps

I managed to fix it by rebooting the device.

My guess is that the android application manager was caching the 'old' name until a reboot. I confirmed this by changing the app name and redeploying - the old name shows in settings->aps until a reboot.

Comment: Good to hear! I figured it was some kind of caching thing.

Comment: Save my day. Thanks.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 4):

It is probably because of your manifest file. If you copied your code and only refactored the package names, eclipse does not change the name of your application in the manifest file.

Either change directly, or use your string.xml files

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: Your package names are different, that's what I see, but are you sure that you changed the app_name from, res/values/string.xml ?

Comment: The application package name is supposed to be different because I needed to do that to install the app twice. And yes I'm sure I changed the string value for the application name. I wonder if there's a bug with the application manager?

Comment: Can you uninstall both of the apps and then install the new one, just to see if notice any difference?

Comment: Okay, so I uninstalled both applications, made sure the string value was renamed to 'package', and reinstalled the original who's app package name is 'my.apps.package'. It's still showing the name under application manager as 'package_DEMO'. Everywhere else, the name on activity pages, the name under "apps" page on device, have the correct application name 'package'.

Answer (score 3):

you can add `android:label="YOUR NAME APP"`

```
 <application
    android:label="YOUR NAME APP"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall the package name by connecting your phone to the pc...

**Go to the command prompt**

```
adb uninstall  packagename
```

so if you want to delete an an app with package name com.example.test

Type : `adb uninstall com.example.test` in command prompt...

**Note :** 
`adb` should in the system path 
or else run this command from your `sdkfolder/platform-tools/`

Comment: This is a good idea for uninstalling but what about force closing? Sometimes I need to do that without being connected to a PC, like when giving a demo. I'm sure I could just uninstall my development build so I only have one version of the app and won't have any confusion, but if I can find a way to fix this issue I'd rather not have to uninstall my development build.

Comment: to force close an app fromcommand line type    adb shell am force-stop packagename......as far as differentiating thm from the device itself ...i am not sure abt it how to do that...however m using a gts5570 thats a slow device so when i open the manager it first shows me the package whil it loads the info ...however its short lived...so m working on it

Comment: why dont you just put a litle trxt in your app and jus set the text of that textview to the package name....by using this code.. getPackageName()   jus call this method. so yul see the package name in both the apps delete force close the app yu wnt ...

Comment: The package names are correct though. I was able to uninstall both versions through command line even though application manager showed something else. As I mentioned though, I need to do this through the application manager and not command line. See my answer though, because I was able to reproduce it and think this was a bug I found.

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled, cleaned, and reinstalled for like the 50th time, and magically the app names are different under the application manager. This must be a system bug, because both versions of the app were showing different names in the activity labels, and under the "apps" page on the device eariler. I'll try seeing if I can reproduce it again.

Comment: I changed the string/app_name value again and reinstalled the app. My new app named appeared under the "apps" page, and on the activity's labels, but again the application manager is showing the old name. So this is reproducible.